# How to access JSON response whose identifier change depending on responsetype in Swift?

Tags: json, swift

I have a JSON query which gives me back one result for success and one result for failure.

However the Identifier is different in these cases.

Case A) Success Result

```
{
result =     {
    "created_at" = "2016-07-25T11:44:26.816Z";
    "created_by" = ol;
    "display_name" = aaaa;
    email = aaaa;
    "fb_id" = "<null>";
    pwd = aaaa;
    roles =         (
        stu
    );
    schools = "<null>";
};
}
```

Case B) Failure

```
{
info = "DETAIL:  Key (email)=(aaaa) already exists.\n";
}
```

For case A) I access the elements as follows:

```
//access the inner array from the json answer called result
        if let response = responseObject as? NSDictionary {
            self.userCredentials = (response as? NSDictionary)!

            print("user Credentials print: ")
           print(self.userCredentials)
            print("user credentials size")
            print(self.userCredentials.count)



            if let displayName = response["result"]!["display_name"] as? String {
                print(displayName)
            }
            if let email = response["result"]!["email"] as? String {
                print(email)
            }
            if let password = response["result"]!["pwd"] as? String {
                print(password)
```

But in case the JSON with identifier "info" appears, the app crashes.
I tried to go with

```
if(response["info"].isEmpty)
```

but this does not work

How can I prevent my code from parsing the values in case the JSON from Case B) is being returned?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your app crashes because you are force unwrapping the result with:

```
response["result"]!["display_name"]
```

Instead, use optional binding to safely unwrap and find out which response you got:

```
if let response = responseObject as? [String:AnyObject] {
    if let result = response["result"] as? [String:AnyObject] {
        // work with the content of "result", for example:
        if let displayName = result["display_name"] {
            print(displayName)
        }
    } else if info = response["info"] as? String {
        // print the info string
        print(info)
    } else {
        // handle the failure to decode
    }
}
```

Comment: Thx. this solution was the easiest for me to understand. works great

Answer (score 2):

Your app crashes because you are force unwrapping the json values:

```
response["result"]!["display_name"]
and so on..
```

So you are basically forcing the app to crash in case of failure response.

One solution is you could unwrap the values safely in if-let blocks.

```
Example:
let x =    [
           "created_at" : "2016-07-25T11:44:26.816Z",
           "Inner_dict" : ["value":"MYVALUE"]
          ]
if let dic = x["Inner_dict"] as? [String:String], val = dic["value"] {
  print(val)
}
```

A better solution could be, the server sets a different status code for the response depending on Success/ Failure. But off course this solution works only if you can edit the server side.

Answer (score 1):

Try with `where`:

```
if let response = responseObject as? NSDictionary where response["info"] == nil {
    // rest of your code
}
```